# How to convert std::string_view to double?

Tags: c++, c++17, string-view

I'm writing a c++ parser for a custom option file for an application. I have a loop that reads lines in the form of `option=value` from a text file where `value` must be converted to `double`. In pseudocode it does the following:

```
while(not EOF)
    statement <- read_from_file
    useful_statement <- remove whitespaces, comments, etc from statement
    equal_position <- find '=' in useful_statement
    option_str <- useful_statement[0:equal_position)
    value_str <- useful_statement[equal_position:end)
    find_option(option_str) <- double(value_str)
```

To handle the string splitting and passing around to functions, I use `std::string_view` because it avoids excessive copying and clearly states the intent of viewing segments of a pre-existing `std::string`. I've done everything to the point where `std::string_view value_str` points to the exact part of `useful_statement` that contains the value I want to extract, but I can't figure out the way to read a `double` from an `std::string_view`.

I know of `std::stod` which doesn't work with `std::string_view`. It allows me to write

```
double value = std::stod(std::string(value_str));
```

However, this is ugly because it converts to a string which is not actually needed, and even though it will presumably not make a noticeable difference in my case, it could be too slow if one had to read a huge amount of numbers from a text file.

On the other hand, `atof` won't work because I can't guarantee a null terminator. I could hack it by adding `\0` to `useful_statement` when constructing it, but that will make the code confusing to a reader and make it too easy to break if the code is altered/refactored.

So, what would be a clean, intuitive and reasonably efficient way to do this?

Comment: Are you ok with using boost? I think you can do this with `boost::convert<double>(stringview);`. I got it off of here... last comment on the page https://github.com/boostorg/convert/issues/29

Comment: Nice find. It's probably `boost::convert<double>(stringview, stringview.length())`, though. It's certainly cleaner than converting to a string and hopefully faster. The only downside is an additional dependency to boost.

Comment: Off topic: Obviously this is psuedocode, but take care in how you implement "while(not EOF)". The trivial `while (!stream.eof())` has a few nasty gotchas.

Comment: user4581301 Usually, one should use something like `while ( stream << statement )` instead…

Comment: Please don't comment on the reading from stream part. I specifically wrote it in pseudocode to keep the discussions on point.

Comment: @MillieSmith @patatahooligan The fix in `boost::convert` to support `std::string_view` is to copy the range to an array and NUL-terminate: https://github.com/boostorg/convert/commit/ab1a43676e04a7c73602e6d1cb2337ea5402c4df

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since you marked your question with C++1z, then that (theoretically) means you have access to [`from_chars`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars). It can handle your string-to-number conversion without needing anything more than a pair of `const char*`s:

```
double dbl;
auto result = from_chars(value_str.data(), value_str.data() + value_str.size(), dbl);
```

Of course, this requires that your standard library provide an implementation of `from_chars`.

Comment: `from_chars()` takes a `double&` not a `double*`. Also that is such an awkward interface... given that nobody provides it, maybe it's a good opportunity to have it take a `string_view`...

Comment: This would be exactly what I'm looking for if it were implemented. I recommend changing the call to`from_chars(&value_str.front(), &value_str.back(), dbl)` for readability, btw. @Barry: there's not much reason to make it take `string_view` Working with `char*` makes it universal and it's trivial to get those from a `string_view`.

Comment: @Barry: It would have been less awkward if `basic_string_view` guaranteed that its iterators were *pointers*.

Comment: @patatahooligan: "*I recommend changing the call to*" That still doesn't work. `back` is the *last* character. It would need to be a pointer *past* the last character.

Comment: Fixed multiple typos. Note that it returns a reference, not a value.

Comment: @patatahooligan: `&back()` is not a pointer past the last character; it is a pointer *to* the last character. Your code would chop off the last character.

Comment: @NicolBolas You don't even need the iterators, could just use `.data()` and `.data() + .size()` just the same as you're basically doing.

Comment: @patatahooligan Taking two arguments to refer to one thing is questionable, calling it "universal" is worse.

Comment: @patatahooligan That isn’t guaranteed to work; `string_view::iterator` might not be a pointer. If it isn’t, it doesn’t matter if you use `back` or `end` as others point out because it won’t compile.

Comment: A sorry I didn't notice it uses the sequence `[first,last)` rather than `[first,last]`. That's kind of annoying...

Comment: @DanielH It's not an iterator according to cppreference.com. The problem is what Nicol Bolas noted. @Barry, it's universal because it works on anything eg `char[]`, `string` and `string_view` and even raw memory if you really want it to.

Comment: I do believe Barry's usage of `.data()` is the cleanest and the most intuitive expression to use.

Comment: @patatahooligan Oops, sorry, I missed that. As for Barry’s comment, all of those can be converted to `string_view` at least as easily as they can be converted to `char*`. For symmetry with `to_chars`, though, I think they made the right decision in having this be the signature (although I wouldn’t have been opposed to a `string_view` overload).

Comment: I just noticed that according to the standard, using `operator[](size_type pos)` with `pos >= size()` is undefined behavior meaning that an implementation is not required to evaluate `&value_str[0]` to something meaningful for empty `string_view`s. On the other hand, `data()` is always required to return a pointer such that the range `[data(); data() + size())` is valid and `from_chars` requires that the range `[first, last)` is valid. Please edit your answer to use `data()` and `data()+size()` to account for the empty `string_view` case.

Comment: I can't find it on the status page this answer links to, but I can confirm that the libstdc++ provided with g++ 8.1 provides from_chars.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom `double` version isn't implemented even in gcc-10. Another `<regex>` like fiasco.

Answer (score 3):

Headers:

```
#include <boost/convert.hpp>
#include <boost/convert/strtol.hpp>
```

Then:

```
std::string x { "aa123.4"};
const std::string_view y(x.c_str()+2, 5); // Window that views the characters "123.4".

auto value = boost::convert<double>(y, boost::cnv::strtol());
if (value.has_value())
{
    cout << value.get() << "\n"; // Prints: 123.4
}
```

Tested Compilers:

- MSVC 2017

---

p.s. Can easily install Boost using vcpkg (defaults to 32-bit, second command is for 64-bit):

```
vcpkg install boost-convert
vcpkg install boost-convert:x64-windows
```

---

Update: Apparently, many Boost functions use string streams internally, which has a lock on the global OS locale. So they have terrible multi-threaded performance**.

I would now recommend something like `stoi()` with substr instead. See: [Safely convert std::string_view to int (like stoi or atoi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56634507/safely-convert-stdstring-view-to-int-like-stoi-or-atoi)

** This strange quirk of Boost renders most of Boost string processing absolutely useless in a multi-threaded environment, which is strange paradox indeed. This is the voice of hard won experience talking - measure it for yourself if you have any doubts. A 48-core machine runs no faster with many Boost calls compared to a 2-core machine. So now I avoid certain parts of Boost like the proverbial plague, as anything can have a dependency on that damn global OS locale lock.