# Safely convert std::string_view to int (like stoi or atoi)

Tags: c++, string, c++17, atoi, string-view

Is there a *safe standard* way to convert `std::string_view` to `int`?

---

Since C++11 `std::string` lets us use `stoi` to convert to `int`:

```cpp
  std::string str = "12345";
  int i1 = stoi(str);              // Works, have i1 = 12345
  int i2 = stoi(str.substr(1,2));  // Works, have i2 = 23

  try {
    int i3 = stoi(std::string("abc"));
  } 
  catch(const std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;  // Correctly throws 'invalid stoi argument'
  }
```

But `stoi` does not support `std::string_view`. So alternatively, we could use `atoi`, but one has to be very careful, e.g.:

```cpp
  std::string_view sv = "12345";
  int i1 = atoi(sv.data());              // Works, have i1 = 12345
  int i2 = atoi(sv.substr(1,2).data());  // Works, but wrong, have i2 = 2345, not 23
```

So `atoi` does not work either, since it is based off the null-terminator `'\0'` (and e.g. `sv.substr` cannot simply insert/add one).

Now, since C++17 there is also `from_chars`, but it does not seem to throw when providing poor inputs:

```cpp
  try {
    int i3;
    std::string_view sv = "abc";
    std::from_chars(sv.data(), sv.data() + sv.size(), i3);
  }
  catch (const std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;  // Does not get called
  }
```

Comment: That's because [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) does not throw anything. Instead it returns an error code.

Comment: When using std::from_chars, as @Yksisarvinen mentioned, you need to check the returmed error code (result.rc). Also, if you intend to be sure that the entire string got converted to a number, you also need to check that result.ptr == sv.data() + sv.size(). Otherwise it will report no error for strings like "12qq".

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The [std::from_chars](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) function does not throw, it only returns a value of type `from_chars_result` which is a struct with two fields:

```
struct from_chars_result {
    const char* ptr;
    std::errc ec;
};
```

You should inspect the values of `ptr` and `ec` when the function returns:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <charconv>

int main()
{
    int i3;
    std::string_view sv = "abc";
    auto result = std::from_chars(sv.data(), sv.data() + sv.size(), i3);
    if (result.ec == std::errc::invalid_argument) {
        std::cout << "Could not convert.";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you intend to be sure that the entire string got converted to a number, you also need to check that result.ptr == sv.data() + sv.size() (otherwise it will report no error for strings like "12qq"), and you also need to check result.ec==errc{}, not against std::errc::invalid_argument specifically, to catch out-of-range errors and such.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, there is no standard way that would throw an exception for you but [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) has a return value code that you may use:

```
#include <charconv>
#include <stdexcept>

template <class T, class... Args>
void from_chars_throws(const char* first, const char* last, T &t, Args... args) {
    std::from_chars_result res = std::from_chars(first, last, t, args... );

    // These two exceptions reflect the behavior of std::stoi.
    if (res.ec == std::errc::invalid_argument) {
        throw std::invalid_argument{"invalid_argument"};
    }
    else if (res.ec == std::errc::result_out_of_range) {
        throw std::out_of_range{"out_of_range"};
    }
}
```

Obviously you can create `svtoi`, `svtol` from this, but the advantage of "extending" `from_chars` is that you only need a single templated function.

Comment: If you intend to be sure that the entire string got converted to a number, you also need to check that result.ptr == last. Otherwise it will report no error for strings like "12qq".

Comment: @SomeGuy The purpose of this answer is to mimic `std::stoi` throwing behavior. `std::stoi` does not throw if there are remaining characters, so this version does not.

Comment: I appreciate what you are saying, but I still think this is something that needs to be clearly understood by anyone using it. In my experience it is pretty much always desirable to convert the entire passed-in string, not just the first few characters of it. Unfortunately, I have encountered fairly few C++ developers who understood that std::stoi silently ignores trailing nonparseable characters, which often leads to subtle bugs. (Also I was recently  bitten by the fact that std::stoi skips leading whitespace but std::from_chars does not, so your code is still not a direct replacement.)

Answer (score 6):

Building on @Ron and @Holt's excellent answers, here's a small wrapper around `std::from_chars()` that returns an optional (`std::nullopt` when the input fails to parse).

```
#include <charconv>
#include <optional>
#include <string_view>

std::optional<int> to_int(const std::string_view & input)
{
    int out;
    const std::from_chars_result result = std::from_chars(input.data(), input.data() + input.size(), out);
    if(result.ec == std::errc::invalid_argument || result.ec == std::errc::result_out_of_range)
    {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: What about when `ec` is some other failure code beside those two?

Comment: @M.M, as best I can tell from [the CppReference docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars), those two are the *only* error codes that `std::from_chars()` will return.

Comment: Why not simply return `out` if `ec` matches `std::errc{}` and `std::nullopt` otherwise? Isn't that the lesser verbose alternative? I also think that `std::string_view`s fall in line with iterators and passing them by value is the way to go.

Comment: If you intend to be sure that the entire string got converted to a number, you also need to check that result.ptr == input.data()+input.size(). Otherwise it will report no error for strings like "12qq".

Answer (score 1):

In C++26, you can do:

```
#include <string_view> // std::string_view
#include <optional> // std::optional
#include <charconv> // std::from_chars

std::optional<int> to_int(const std::string_view string) {
    int result;
    return std::from_chars(string.data(), string.data() + string.size(), result)
        ? result : std::nullopt;
}
```

thanks to `std::from_chars_result`’s `operator bool()`.

Answer (score 0):

As @some-guy mentioned in the comments, you need to examine both `std::from_chars_result::ptr` and `std::from_chars_result::ec`. Otherwise the parsing can happily stop in the middle of the string.

Here's a function template that accepts all numeric types:

```
#include <charconv>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string_view>

template <class T, class... Args>
T from_chars(std::string_view s, Args... args)
{
    const char *end = s.begin() + s.size();
    T number;
    auto result = std::from_chars(s.begin(), end, number, args...);
    if (result.ec != std::errc{} || result.ptr != end)
        throw std::runtime_error("Cannot convert to number");
    return number;
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = from_chars<int>("42");
    std::cout << i << '\n';
    i = from_chars<int>("1a", 16);
    std::cout << i << '\n';
    float f = from_chars<float>("10.5");
    std::cout << f << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you are worrying about.
Anyways I did a test for you.
For the string length of any int, which fit into small string optimization, the time took to convert a string_view to string: 1.0498 nanoseconds.
Even for longer strings that do not fit, it takes: 8.748 nanoseconds.

So just convert it to string and then int probably in a inline function so you have your own "safe standard" way:)