# how to convert string to int like the example given below

Tags: c++

I have a string and i want to acces the number inside the string.

I have tried something like that,

```
string s="the number is 2.";
int number= stoi(s[14]);
```

I just want to access 2. I have used stoi but it hasn't work. what should i do?

Comment: `int number= std::stoi(std::string{s[14]});`

Comment: Will this "number" always contain a single digit? Or could it have multiple digits?

Comment: it can be multiple digits.

Comment: Edited the answer to deal with multiple digits.

Comment: In what way "it hasn't work"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) expects a `std::string`, not a `char`. If you want a single `char`, you can get it out of the string like this:

```
int number = std::stoi(s.substr(14,1));
```

If you have more than 1 digit in the number you want to convert, you can just do:

```
int number = std::stoi(s.substr(14));
```

which will extract as many digits after the position as it can, to generate a number.

Comment: This assumes that the number is exactly one character long. If "the number is 10", this will return 1.

Comment: True, but OP says they "just want to access 2".

Comment: Then an equivalent answer would be "int number=2". :) I'd speculate the OP is after an arbitrary integer, not specifically after 2.

Comment: Fair enough, let's see what the OP says. I'll edit the answer if so.

Comment: Constructing a `std::string` just for this is incredibly wasteful.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings with small string optimization, likely it's not wasteful at all. And it's not like there is a better alternative short of rolling your own `stoi` which takes a string_view instead of a string.

Comment: @Ayxan Okay, granted, the single-character version might not be _so_ bad if SSO is in play. The second example not necessarily so, though. Sadly, the need for null termination makes [rolling your own a bit of a faff...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56634507/4386278)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Seems a bit like a premature optimization to me. And anyway, at that point, showing that option would be beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Yeah, it would be. Still, there's a difference between "premature optimization" and "not needlessly writing inefficient code" ;)

Comment: Absolutely :) In this case, I think this is about as efficient as it needs to be, unless shown to be a bottleneck.

Comment: @ast I don't agree. Any number you can possibly pass is less than 20 digits long. Copying that with SSO is super fast, a single memcpy, and as I said, it's not like there is a convenient and more efficient alternative.

Comment: @Ayxan The input could be 4GB long. You'd be copying that to extract max 20 chars. It doesn't scale.

Comment: @ast I've been thinking about this and my conclusion is that the best solution is to use [Remy Lebeau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61962368/10147399) and maybe consider [from_chars](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars).

Comment: @Ayxan Yep, I think so too.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert `char` digits to its numerical value by using a simple arithmetic conversion from `char` to `int`:

```
std::string s ="the number is 2.";
int number = s[14] - '0';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::string::find_first_of()` to find the position of the first digit, then use `std::string::find_first_not_of()` to find the position after the last digit, and then use `std::string::substr()` to extract a sub-string containing just the digits, and then finally use `std::stoi()` to convert the sub-string into an `int`:

```
string s = "the number is 2.";
auto start = s.find_first_of("0123456789");
auto end = s.find_first_not_of("0123456789", start);
int number = stoi(s.substr(start, end-start));
```

Alternatively, after using `std::string::find_first_of()` to find the position of the first digit, you can then pass `std::string::c_str()` offset by the position to `std::strtol()`:

```
string s = "the number is 2.";
auto start = s.find_first_of("0123456789");
int number = std::strtol(str.c_str() + start, nullptr, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a conversion logic that doesn't assume a single digit number, here's a slightly more universal snippet:

```
string s="the number is 234.";
int number= atoi(s.c_str() + 14);
```