# How to achieve std::from_chars() with only c++ 14

Tags: c++, boost, c++14

I'm trying to convert a boost::string_view to an integer. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56634507/) discusses using `from_chars()`, but this is available in C++17 and I'm looking for a C++14 solution.

What would be the best option here?

Comment: [`std::strtol()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) takes a `const char*` as input, and you can get a `const char*` from a `string_view`

Comment: If you're already using Boost, consider using `boost::lexical_cast`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau A `string_view` might not be null-terminated.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat hmm, good point. Well, then just copy the `string_view` to a `std::string` first and then use that with `std::stoi()`/`std::strtol()`. Not ideal, but it would work. [`boost::lexical_cast` doesn't work with `string_view`](https://github.com/boostorg/lexical_cast/issues/30).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Does that work without a allocating a string? I came up with an answer that allows parsing with copying/allocation, various radix and integer types (online demo https://godbolt.org/z/si5LDK)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the spirit [sic] of [@t-niese's now-deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62052445/timeline) I'd suggest a Spirit approach. Since C++14 is on the table, let's use X3:

```
template <typename Int = int, unsigned Radix=10>
Int parse_int(std::string_view sv) {
    static constexpr boost::spirit::x3::int_parser<Int, Radix> p{};
    Int val;
    if (!parse(begin(sv), end(sv), p, val))
        throw std::runtime_error("parse_int");
    return val;
}
```

This surprisingly small thing does surprisingly many things. It can parse into any integer type, including non-standard (like Boost Multiprecision, GMP or MPFR).

> You can even make it parse integers into non-integral types if you really want although it will not parse non-integer formats, see [How to parse space-separated floats in C++ quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465061/how-to-parse-space-separated-floats-in-c-quickly/17479702#17479702) for that if you're interested in more.
>
> Also see there to learn just how performant these routines are in practice.

### Test Cases

```
int main() {
    expect("0", 0);
    expect("+0", 0);
    expect("-0", 0);
    expect("+1", 1);
    expect("-1", -1);
    expect<int8_t>("-127", -127);
    expect<int8_t>("-128", -128);

    // edge case
    expect<uint8_t>("-1", -1);                     // surprising?
    expect<unsigned long>("-1", std::stoul("-1")); // Nope, matches stoul!

    auto std_roundtrip = [](auto value) { expect(std::to_string(value), value); };
    std_roundtrip(std::numeric_limits<intmax_t>::min());
    std_roundtrip(std::numeric_limits<intmax_t>::max());
    std_roundtrip(std::numeric_limits<uintmax_t>::min());
    std_roundtrip(std::numeric_limits<uintmax_t>::max());

    // radix
    expect<int, 2>("-01011", -11);
    expect<int, 8>("-01011", -521);
    expect<int, 16>("a0", 160);

    // invalids
    should_fail(""); // empty
    should_fail("+"); // lone sign
    should_fail("+ 9999"); // space

    // extensibility:
    using Large = boost::multiprecision::int1024_t;
    for (auto huge : { Large(42) << 700, -(Large(42) << 701) })
        expect(boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(huge), huge);

    // doesn't require the target type to be integral either
    using Decimal = boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_50;
    expect<Decimal>("123456789", 123456789);
    // but it's still an integer parser:
    should_fail<Decimal>("1e10");
    should_fail<Decimal>("1.0");
}
```

Prints

```
"0" -> 0 OK
"+0" -> 0 OK
"-0" -> 0 OK
"+1" -> 1 OK
"-1" -> -1 OK
"-127" ->  OK
"-128" -> € OK
"-1" -> ÿ OK
"-1" -> 18446744073709551615 OK
"-9223372036854775808" -> -9223372036854775808 OK
"9223372036854775807" -> 9223372036854775807 OK
"0" -> 0 OK
"18446744073709551615" -> 18446744073709551615 OK
"-01011" -> -11 OK
"-01011" -> -521 OK
"a0" -> 160 OK
 OK (should not parse)
 OK (should not parse)
 OK (should not parse)
"220925707865031687304121575080965403953114271718573302098927797928886750480477394528773994523658714951533284691959485143946816154507719762251368220367378995698119394187394673124049877831141554125394316572902817792" -> 220925707865031687304121575080965403953114271718573302098927797928886750480477394528773994523658714951533284691959485143946816154507719762251368220367378995698119394187394673124049877831141554125394316572902817792 OK
"-441851415730063374608243150161930807906228543437146604197855595857773500960954789057547989047317429903066569383918970287893632309015439524502736440734757991396238788374789346248099755662283108250788633145805635584" -> -441851415730063374608243150161930807906228543437146604197855595857773500960954789057547989047317429903066569383918970287893632309015439524502736440734757991396238788374789346248099755662283108250788633145805635584 OK
"123456789" -> 1.23457e+08 OK
 OK (should not parse)
 OK (should not parse)
```

### FULL LISTING

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3a7871112c36f1f)**

> NOTE UPDATED to the better non-throwing interface which updates the string_view to reflect what part of input was consumed (see below in **BONUS TOPICS**). Last two tests now print:
>
> ```
> "3e10" -> 3 OK
>  -> trailing "e10"
> "-7.0" -> -7 OK
>  -> trailing ".0"
> ```

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

template <typename Int = int, unsigned Radix=10>
static inline std::optional<Int> parse_int(std::string_view& remain) {
    static constexpr boost::spirit::x3::int_parser<Int, Radix> p{};
    Int val;
    auto f = begin(remain), l = end(remain);
    if (!parse(f, l, p, val))
        return std::nullopt;
    remain = remain.substr(f - begin(remain));
    return val;
}

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

template <typename Int>
std::string to_string(Int const& value) {
    using widen = std::common_type_t<int, Int>; // pesky chars keep showing as non-numbers
    return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(static_cast<widen>(value));
}

template <typename Int = int, unsigned Radix = 10>
void expect(std::string_view input, Int expected) {
    std::cout << std::quoted(input);
    if (auto actual = parse_int<Int, Radix>(input)) {
        if (expected == actual.value())
            std::cout << " -> " << to_string(actual.value()) << " OK\n";
        else
            std::cout << " -> " << to_string(actual.value()) << " MISMATCH (" << to_string(expected) << " expected instead)\n";

        if (!input.empty())
            std::cout << " -> trailing " << std::quoted(input) << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << " FAILED (" << to_string(expected) << " expected instead)\n";
    }
}

template <typename Int = int, unsigned Radix = 10>
void should_fail(std::string_view input) {
    std::cout << std::quoted(input);
    if (auto actual = parse_int<Int, Radix>(input)) {
        std::cout << " -> " << to_string(actual.value())
            << " MISMATCH (expected to fail parse instead)\n";
        if (!input.empty())
            std::cout << " -> trailing " << std::quoted(input) << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << " OK (should not parse)\n";
    }
}

#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

int main() {
    expect("0", 0);
    expect("+0", 0);
    expect("-0", 0);
    expect("+1", 1);
    expect("-1", -1);
    expect<int8_t>("-127", -127);
    expect<int8_t>("-128", -128);

    // edge case
    expect<uint8_t>("-1", -1);                     // surprising?
    expect<unsigned long>("-1", std::stoul("-1")); // Nope, matches stoul!

    auto std_roundtrip = [](auto value) { expect(std::to_string(value), value); };
    std_roundtrip(std::numeric_limits<intmax_t>::min());
    std_roundtrip(std::numeric_limits<intmax_t>::max());
    std_roundtrip(std::numeric_limits<uintmax_t>::min());
    std_roundtrip(std::numeric_limits<uintmax_t>::max());

    // radix
    expect<int, 2>("-01011", -11);
    expect<int, 8>("-01011", -521);
    expect<int, 16>("a0", 160);

    // invalids
    should_fail(""); // empty
    should_fail("+"); // lone sign
    should_fail("+ 9999"); // space

    // extensibility:
    using Large = boost::multiprecision::int1024_t;
    for (auto huge : { Large(42) << 700, -(Large(42) << 701) })
        expect(boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(huge), huge);

    // doesn't require the target type to be integral either
    using Decimal = boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_50;
    expect<Decimal>("123456789", 123456789);
    // but it's still an integer parser:
    expect<Decimal>("3e10", 3);
    expect<Decimal>("-7.0", -7);
}
```

### BONUS TOPICS

- To parse strictly unsigned integers (so `-1` becomes invalid input), replace `x3::int_parser` with `x3::uint_parser`. (Note that the target type can be signed regardless of allowed input formats).

  ```
  template <typename Int = int, unsigned Radix=10>
  Int parse_uint(std::string_view sv) {
      static constexpr boost::spirit::x3::uint_parser<Int, Radix> p{};
      Int val;
      if (!parse(begin(sv), end(sv), p >> boost::spirit::x3::eoi, val))
          throw std::runtime_error("parse_int");
      return val;
  }
  ```
- To get the `from_chars` behaviour where you are left with the next character unparsed, just drop the `x3::eoi` expression:

  ```
  template <typename Int = int, unsigned Radix=10>
  Int parse_int(std::string_view sv, std::string_view& remain) {
      static constexpr boost::spirit::x3::int_parser<Int, Radix> p{};
      Int val;
      auto f = begin(sv), l = end(sv);
      if (!parse(f, l, p, val))
          throw std::runtime_error("parse_int");
      remain = { &*f, size_t(std::distance(f,l)) };
      return val;
  }
  ```

  See its behaviour **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b3538dcfe41ddde)**

  ```
  std::string_view input = "123bogus", remain;

  std::cout
      << "input: " << std::quoted(input) << " -> "
      << parse_int(input, remain)
      << " remaining: " << std::quoted(remain)
      << std::endl;
  ```

  Prints

  ```
   input: "123bogus" -> 123 remaining: "bogus"
  ```
- Actually, as an afterthought, `optional<>` could be far better than exceptions to signal failure:

  ```
    template <typename Int = int, unsigned Radix=10>
  static inline std::optional<Int> parse_int(std::string_view& remain) {
      static constexpr boost::spirit::x3::int_parser<Int, Radix> p{};
      Int val;
      auto f = begin(remain), l = end(remain);
      if (!parse(f, l, p, val))
          return std::nullopt;
      remain = remain.substr(f - begin(remain));
      return val;
  }
  ```

  Combines the best of both worlds. And e.g. this:

  ```
  int main() {
      auto input = "123bogus";
      std::string_view remain = input;

      if (auto parsed = parse_int(remain)) 
          printf("input: '%s' -> %d remaining: '%s'\n",
                  input, parsed.value(), remain.data());
  }
  ```

  Compiles ***all the way down to***: [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/si5LDK)

  ```
  .LC0:
          .string "123bogus"
  .LC1:
          .string "input: '%s' -> %d remaining: '%s'\n"
  main:
          sub     rsp, 8
          mov     ecx, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0+3
          mov     edx, 123
          xor     eax, eax
          mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
          mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
          call    printf
          xor     eax, eax
          add     rsp, 8
          ret
  ```

Comment: Added `parse_uint` and remaining unparsed input indication as **BONUS** topics. Also, see this neat [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/si5LDK) to see how it all inlines away (also the interface with `optional<>` return instead of an exception seems much nicer come to think of it)

Comment: @t-niese I'm not sure why you deleted your answer, maybe you can share your comments if it applies to this answer as well.

Comment: I deleted the answer because while my code compiled fine with c++17, it resulted in a huge number of compile errors using c++14 and I had no time anymore to figure out if the shown code required c++17 or if the problem was somewhere else.

Comment: Seems to compile fine now, not sure what went wrong yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

In boost you could use `spirit::qi`, to parse a sequence given by iterators into a numeric type:

**[Live On C++03](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/185b3fc5145672cc)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/string_view.hpp> 

int main() {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    boost::string_view number_view("12345");
    int dest;

    if (qi::parse(
          number_view.begin(), number_view.end(), 
          qi::int_,
          dest)) {
       std::cout << dest << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Prints

```
12345
```

Comment: Also on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/rtPLVX) showing that compilers are awesome.